# iometer - cpu utilization not being returned

Tags: linux, vmware-esx, iometer

everything I want gets picked up from the dynamo process.

Although for some reason the CPU Utilization isn't being presented and recorded.

Any ideas?

Thank you

EDIT:

SYSTEM - Linux x86_64, Virtual Machine, running atop ESX4.0 on an IBM HS21 Blade

Comment: I'm assuming Linux, is that correct?

Comment: Just to clarify, everything works perfectly except the CPU Utilization? I believe that's what you said but I want to make sure I understand.

Comment: yes - my mistake. Linux it is. x86_64. It's a VM to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Whether your tools works or not CPU measurement from within a VM is utterly pointless, any data you get is flawed. This is because the OS and/or tool assumes it has full control of the (actually virtual) CPU so measurement is based on load over time and time isn't linear in VM-land due to time-slicing.

Measure from the hypervisor, it's the only way to *know* what's going on.

Comment: You're absolutely right - if there is contention for the CPU. In my case this is the only virtual machine running on the host apart from the ESX console itself.
Understandably there is a slight hit in the guarantee and scheduling that is incurred from ESX, but am not interested in those variations.

Am after the cost per io operation.

Comment: Host utilisation is irrelevant - VM CPU measurement is **ALWAYS** wrong, in all circumstances - it's actually a question on in the VCP 3 & 4 exams.

Comment: Chopper, yes - its off the 100% ideal. This isn't the issue here, as the IO cost will still be the same, as whilst the VM is 'sleeping' in between the ESX-CPU scheduling, so is the IO within that machine.